# What is the use of \n while scanning two integers like in scanf("%d \n %d")?

Tags: c, scanf

I found this the above type of code in a pre-completed portion of a coding question in Hackerrank. I was wondering what `\n` would do? Does it make any difference?

Comment: It will also read a newline from stranded input .

Comment: It's the new character. used to go to the next line and start printing the next decimal from there

Comment: `Does it make any difference` Difference vs. what? `"%d \n %d"` works the same as `"%d %d"`, or `"%d%d"` for that matter.

Comment: @KhaledGaber: A `\n` in a `scanf()` format string (outside of a scan set `%[…]`) is equivalent to a space — it eats white space, meaning blanks, tabs, newlines.  The number is not restricted; it is zero or more.  After a space in the format, it is a no-op; the space has done the same job that the newline would do.

Comment: @anoopknr: A `\n` in a `scanf()` format string (outside of a scan set `%[…]`) is equivalent to a space — it eats white space, meaning blanks, tabs, newlines.  The number is not restricted; it is zero or more.  After a space in the format, it is a no-op; the space has done the same job that the newline would do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read some good [C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) website, and perhaps the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) and probably [*Modern C*](http://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/).

The documentation of [scanf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) explains what is happening for `\n` in the format control string. It is handled like a space   and matches a sequence of space characters (such as `' '`, or `'\t'`, or `'\n'`) in the input stream.

If you explicitly want to parse lines, you would use some parser generator like [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) and/or use first [fgets(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) or [getline(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) and later [sscanf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html).

Don't forget to handle error cases. See [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html). Consider documenting using [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBNF) notation the valid inputs of your program.

Study for inspiration the source code of existing open source programs, including [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/). Be aware than in 2020 [UTF-8](https://utf8everywhere.org/) should be used everywhere (then you might want to use [libunistring](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/) whose source code you could study and improve, since it is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html)).

If you use Linux, consider using [gdb(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html) or [ltrace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html) to understand the behavior of your program. Of course, read the documentation of your C compiler (perhaps [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)) and debugger (perhaps [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)).

Comment: really interesting to see a professional answer from a professional to a newbie, thanks for your interest sir.